# Issue on Mod security Rules

Tags: mod-security, mod-security2

I have successfully implemented Modsecurity Firewall.

But My Team facing one issue related to Firewall rule for Sql Injection & Xss.

Issue is. Whenever user add normal information with special character then rules can execute and display page with error 403 forbidden. And in Apache error log got various line number which is rules line. I was comment it each rule like rule no (309,508) in `modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attack.conf` & (223,233,243,237,211,239,49,136) in `modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injeciton.conf`.

which is give me false positive result.

> Testing scenario is
>
> ## input Text
>
> Only 8 Seats left! REGISTER NOW!
>
> Course Fees include Course material, Hands on training, working Lunch,
>   Breakfast, evening tea.
>
> ** Free accommodation will be provided on prior request
>
> For accommodation, please contact us on: +91 12345 67890
>   ================================================== Errorlog in apache
>
> Sahil: [Wed Mar 16 10:29:57.316380 2016] [:error] [pid
>   25001]ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern
>   match "(?i:[\"\\'][ ](([^a-z0-9~_:\\' ])|(in)).+?\\(.?\\))"
>   at
>   ARGS_NAMES:redirect:${#res=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),#res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"),#req=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'),#res.getWriter().print("dir:"),#res.getWriter().println(#req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")),#res.getWriter().flush(),#res.getWriter().close()}.
>   [file
>   "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf"]
>   [line "506"] [id "973335"] [rev "2"] [msg "IE XSS Filters - Attack
>   Detected."] [data "Matched Data:
>   '),#res.setCharacterEncoding(\x22UTF-8\x22) found within
>   ARGS_NAMES:redirect:${#res=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),#res.setCharacterEncoding(\x22UTF-8\x22),#req=#context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'),#res.getWriter().print(\x22dir:\x22),#res.getWriter().println(#req.getSession().
>   [hostname "54.169.124.26"] [uri "/"] [unique_id
>   "Vuk1pawfC1wAAGGpqA8AAAAS"]

So will you please give guidance for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

You should add an exception like this in config after loading this `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_xss_attacks.conf` file:

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 973335 !ARG_NAMES:'/redirect.*/'
```

Might also be interested in this answer:
[Extra sensitive Mod Security rules giving 403 forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676348/extra-sensitive-mod-security-rules-giving-403-forbidden-error/33750934#33750934)