# How can I prevent Modsecurity false positives caused by SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, iis-8, mod-security, false-positive

I recently built a brand new development server in order to experiment with Modsecurity. However I am getting lots of false-positives generated by a .NET 4 application using SignalR for client-server communications.

**How can I prevent false-positives without compromizing Modsecurity's efficiency?**

The hits seems pretty generic so I do not want to disable the rules altogether and I would like to avoid disabling hits on `/signalr/` uri which would forfeit protection on SignalR.

Here is how I proceeded with my setup:

1. I installed Windows Server 2012
2. Installed IIS Role
3. Installed all OS Updates
4. Installed ModSecurity IIS via WebPlatformInstaller
5. Created website and deployed application

Here are the three common false positives I get:

SQL Authentication bypass:

```
> [client 192.168.0.104:59945] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match
> "(?i:(?:in\\s*?\\(+\\s*?select)|(?:(?:n?and|x?x?or|div|like|between|and|not
> |\\|\\||\\&\\&)\\s+[\\s\\w+]+(?:regexp\\s*?\\(|sounds\\s+like\\s*?[\"'`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98]|[=\\d]+x))|([\"'`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98]\\s*?\\d\\s*?(?:--|#))
> ..." at ARGS:connectionData. [file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity
> IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"]
> [line "239"] [id "981246"] [msg "Detects basic SQL authentication
> bypass attempts 3/3"] [data "Matched Data: \x22name\x22:\x22 found
> within ARGS:connectionData: [{\x22name\x22:\x22*****serverhub\x22}]"]
> [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"]
> [hostname "*********"] [uri
> "/signalr/start?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=iIxfXzLxKm9twEhHdomj4DI95so0QmpmqeTXD4Qe0VsQoJO47CHuEIuv2z7M%2B1TYx44PK5ko18t2aoaLb4WztjR1c8g0VP8MUaGkSO9KDftOzsGektSIDl%2FI1RPMQdTd&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22*****serverhub%22%7D%5D&_=1461637088340"]
> [unique_id "17798225729515683844"]
```

Restricted SQL  characters:

```
> [client 192.168.0.104:59945] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match
> "([\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\-\\+\\=\\{\\}\\[\\]\\|\\:\\;\"\\'\\\xc2\xb4\\\xe2\x80\x99\\\xe2\x80\x98\\`\\<\\>].*?){4,}"
> at ARGS:connectionData. [file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity
> IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"]
> [line "159"] [id "981173"] [rev "2"] [msg "Restricted SQL Character
> Anomaly Detection Alert - Total # of special characters exceeded"]
> [data "Matched Data: \x22 found within ARGS:connectionData:
> [{\x22name\x22:\x22*****serverhub\x22}]"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"]
> [maturity "9"] [accuracy "8"] [tag
> "OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [hostname "*********"] [uri
> "/signalr/start?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=iIxfXzLxKm9twEhHdomj4DI95so0QmpmqeTXD4Qe0VsQoJO47CHuEIuv2z7M%2B1TYx44PK5ko18t2aoaLb4WztjR1c8g0VP8MUaGkSO9KDftOzsGektSIDl%2FI1RPMQdTd&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22*****serverhub%22%7D%5D&_=1461637088340"]
> [unique_id "17798225729515683844"]
```

Missing Accept Header:

```
> [client 192.168.0.104:59949] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator EQ matched
> 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "C:\/Program Files/ModSecurity
> IIS/owasp_crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf"]
> [line "47"] [id "960015"] [rev "1"] [msg "Request Missing an Accept
> Header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.9"] [maturity "9"]
> [accuracy "9"] [tag
> "OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_ACCEPT"] [tag
> "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A7"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname
> "*********"] [uri
> "/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=iIxfXzLxKm9twEhHdomj4DI95so0QmpmqeTXD4Qe0VsQoJO47CHuEIuv2z7M%2B1TYx44PK5ko18t2aoaLb4WztjR1c8g0VP8MUaGkSO9KDftOzsGektSIDl%2FI1RPMQdTd&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22*****serverhub%22%7D%5D&tid=6"]
> [unique_id "17726168135477755906"]
```

PS: I am not using any SQL technology in that particular application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first two I would suggest you add the following rules to ignore this ConnectionData parameter for those rules:

```
 SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981246 !ARGS:'ConnectionData'
 SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981173 !ARGS:'ConnectionData'
```

For the last I suggest removing that rule completely. I don't find it that useful as there are some browsers (on Android from memory) that don't send that header:

```
SecRuleRemoveById 960015
```

You might want to read this answer to understand how to tune ModSecurity:
[Extra sensitive Mod Security rules giving 403 forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676348/extra-sensitive-mod-security-rules-giving-403-forbidden-error/33750934#33750934)

Comment: Great answer especially combined with the referred "Extra sensitive Mod Security rules giving 403 forbidden error" which gives aditionnal context.